# issue installing waveshare 3.2 LCD screen on my pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I was trying to install this LCD http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.2inch_RPi_LCD_(B) on my pie 3 with jessie but, when I use the drivers listed on this website the pi reboots and runs into a kernel panic. I found this other solution at https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware/issues/6#issuecomment-278301082 but, the screen turns from white to block. I can see some of the booting sequence on the screen but, after it books it goes black. Anyone know the correct way to install this? I contacted waveshare and they suggested to install their image that includes the drivers but, I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: Why the discomfort trusting their driver is no worse than trusting their image or a third party's driver as you have already done.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I did not understand your comment.

Comment: Why do you not feel comfortable using their image?

Comment: My comment addresses the security implications. Using any third party code comes with inhernet risks, and the risks are no different for a complete disk image than for a driver etc.